# get_permalink returns to attachment url in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, attachment

```
$parent_id = $post->post_parent;
echo get_permalink($parent_id);
```

I have a custom type where I post photo galleries using default wordpress media and when I click on any image opens the image.php (attachment url) Here Im trying to add a go back to gallery link but it allways returns to the actual attachment url and refreshes the page.

do you have any idea how can I get the correct parent post permalink to go back to all images in the post?

Im trying to create the link in image.php

```
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); 
        global $post;
        $parent_id = $post->post_parent;
        ?>
          <div style="background: #292929;padding-top:3px;text-align:center;">
          <a href="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url($post->ID); ?>">
          <?php echo wp_get_attachment_image( get_the_ID(), 'large' ); ?>
          </a>
          </div>
        <?php //the_content(); ?>
        <nav id="image-navigation" class="navigation image-navigation">
            <div class="nav-links">
                 <?php previous_image_link( false, '<div class="previous-image"><i class="fa fa-arrow-left" aria-hidden="true"></i> ' . __( 'Previous Image', 'albano' ) . '</div>' ); ?>
                 <?php //echo back_to_gallery(); ?>
                 <?php echo get_permalink($post->post_parent); ?>
                 <?php next_image_link( false, '<div class="next-image">' . __( 'Next Image', 'albano' ) . ' <i class="fa fa-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>' ); ?>
             </div><!-- .nav-links -->
        </nav><!-- #image-navigation -->
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
        <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>
```

output is the url of the current page and not the parent post. `<?php echo get_permalink($post->post_parent); ?>`

Comment: Can you post the HTML + PHP code where you create the link ?

Comment: Actually WordPress not doing this, You browser is not opening directly the image URL. The solution is you can add some css features like popup gallery, etc.

Comment: The wordpress does it very well its working fine @Sunil Dora the only problem is that I cant go back to the single post where all images are.

Comment: @Alessandro the updated one is the loop of image.php, so I didnt include all code with get_footer or header

Comment: Any one can help?

Comment: Have you checked what `$post->parent` is actually returning? It giving you the current page ID to me suggests something is not working and is defaulting to current post ID. You could also try `wp_get_post_parent_id( $post_ID );`

Comment: returning the attachment url instead of the parent post this is the problem that I'm asking

Comment: The post has 12 images as gallery when you click on an y image you go automatically to the image.php or lets say to the attachment just need an url which goes back to 12 images again.

Comment: tried also `$current_attachment = get_queried_object(); echo get_attachment_link($current_attachment->post_parent);` but the same returns to the image url instead of the  parent post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Soluion was simple:

Added new labels in the custom post type register function.

```
'parent' => __('Parent galleries','albano'),
'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent:', 'albano' ),
```

And I used the following function:

```
function back_to_gallery() {
    if ( !is_attachment() && is_singular('gallery') )
    return false;
    $current_attachment = get_queried_object();
    $permalink = get_permalink( $current_attachment->post_parent );
    $parent_title = get_post( $current_attachment->post_parent )->post_title;
    $link = '<a class="back-to-gallery" href="' . $permalink  . '"  title="' . $parent_title . '">' . __('Back to gallery', 'albano') . '</a>';
    return $link;
}
```

The function will give the go back to parent post url with the following output: `echo back_to_gallery();`